# How I can open .vcf file in browser using react.js without showing download message

Tags: ios, reactjs, browser, vcf-vcard

I am trying to open a .vcf in safari after creating it but it shows me download option and view option as you can see in image.
[image: result image]
I do not want to show download message. What I want is to open the temp.vcf file so user can save it to phone. My code is

```
  handleVCF() {
  const FileSaver = require('file-saver');
  var socilaURls = "";
  var telNum = "";
  this.state.socialLinks.forEach((doc)=>{
    if (doc.inCntctForm === true){
    if (doc.mediaTmp === "Text"){
      telNum =  "\nTEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:"+doc.mediaId;
    }
    else{
    var ret = doc.mediaId.replace('https://www.','');
    ret = ret.replace('HTTPS://www.','');
    ret = ret.replace('http://www.','');
    ret = ret.replace('HTTP://www.','');
    socilaURls = socilaURls+"\nX-SOCIALPROFILE;TYPE="+doc.mediaName+";CHARSET=UTF-8:x-user="+ret+":"+doc.mediaUrl;
    }
  }
  })
var userNameTmp = "";
if (this.isNameInclude === "true"){
  userNameTmp = this.state.fullName;
}else{
  userNameTmp = "user"
}
var file = new Blob(
  [
    `BEGIN:VCARD 
    VERSION:4.0
    N:${userNameTmp};;;
    PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:${this.base64Image}
    ${telNum}
    EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=pref:${this.state.email}
    item1.URL:${this.state.profileUrl}
    item1.X-ABLabel:My Dappy profile
    ${socilaURls}
    NOTE;CHARSET=UTF-8:Hard press on the profile picture above to save this contact to your phone!
    END:VCARD`
  ],
  { type: "text/vcard;charset=utf-8" }
);
FileSaver.saveAs(file,"temp.vcf");
window.open(file);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @AWebb haven't find yet